# PHP: how to get a list of classes that implement certain interface?

Tags: php, oop, class

I've got an interface

```
interface IModule {
    public function Install();
}
```

and some classes that implement this interface

```
class Module1 implements IModule {
    public function Install() {
        return true;
    }
}

class Module2 implements IModule {
    public function Install() {
        return true;
    }
}

...

class ModuleN implements IModule {
    public function Install() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

How to get a list of all classes that implement this interface?
I'd like to get this list with PHP.

Comment: You should probably clarify whether you want to get the list within PHP or just want to generate such a list for documentation purposes, etc.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You dont need Reflection for this. You can simply use

- [`class_implements`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php) — Return the interfaces which are implemented by the given class

**Usage**

```
in_array('InterfaceName', class_implements('className'));
```

**Example 1 - Echo all classes implementing the Iterator Interface**

```
foreach (get_declared_classes() as $className) {
    if (in_array('Iterator', class_implements($className))) {
        echo $className, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Example 2 - Return array of all classes implementing the Iterator Interface**

```
print_r(
    array_filter(
        get_declared_classes(), 
        function ($className) {
            return in_array('Iterator', class_implements($className));
        }
    )
);
```

The second example requires PHP5.3 due to the callback being an anonymous function.

Comment: If you wrap it on a function for example, and use "::class" isn't gonna work:
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bvf8-izy6

Comment: One can use `is_subclass_of($className, $interfaceName)` instead of `in_array()` and `class_implements()`.

Answer (score 34):

You can use PHP's [`ReflectionClass::implementsInterface`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.implementsinterface.php) and [`get_declared_classes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php) functions to accomplish this:

```
$classes = get_declared_classes();
$implementsIModule = array();
foreach($classes as $klass) {
   $reflect = new ReflectionClass($klass);
   if($reflect->implementsInterface('IModule')) 
      $implementsIModule[] = $klass;
}
```

Comment: Note: This doesn't work if you're loading IModules via `__autoload`. But +1.

Comment: 7 years late comment, but here is an example of how you can use files in Composers autoload to ensure that some specific files will be loaded every time and be available with get_declared_classes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18671530/143279

Comment: The whole problem with all of the answers here is `get_declared_classes()`. There is almost no case when you have declared ALL of your classes before running that code.

Answer (score 13):

Generic solution:

```
function getImplementingClasses( $interfaceName ) {
    return array_filter(
        get_declared_classes(),
        function( $className ) use ( $interfaceName ) {
            return in_array( $interfaceName, class_implements( $className ) );
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Not work in this scenary: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bvf8-izy6

Answer (score 6):

To check who implements a particular interface, you can write a function like below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Get classes which implement a given interface 
 * @param string $interface_name Name of the interface
 * @return array Array of names of classes. Empty array means input is a valid interface which no class is implementing. NULL means input is not even a valid interface name.
 */
function whoImplements($interface_name) {
    if (interface_exists($interface_name)) {
        return array_filter(get_declared_classes(), create_function('$className', "return in_array(\"$interface_name\", class_implements(\"\$className\"));"));
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Output of an example call `var_export(whoImplements('ArrayAccess'));` will be as follows:
`[sandbox]$ php whoimplementswhat.php
Array
(
    [29] => CachingIterator
    [30] => RecursiveCachingIterator
    [38] => ArrayObject
    [39] => ArrayIterator
    [40] => RecursiveArrayIterator
    [48] => SplDoublyLinkedList
    [49] => SplQueue
    [50] => SplStack
    [55] => SplFixedArray
    [56] => SplObjectStorage
    [111] => Phar
    [112] => PharData
)`

This way, you don't use loops and you can run your code on lower versions of PHP. Function `array_filter` loops internally, but inside PHP execution engine (hence more performant than loops written in PHP code).

Comment: This way, you don't use loops and you can run the code on lower versions of PHP.

Comment: Do you have any idea why I see an empty array, although I'm definitely implementing the interface?

Comment: @Netbulae There must be something wrong. Put your code in codepad and share a link.

Comment: Ah it's alright. Hint: the classes were not declared. I was using the Wishful Thinking design pattern :p

Comment: `array_filter` still loops the entire array internally, so the "don't use loops" statement is incorrect.

Comment: @Andy Loops inside PHP execution engine are way more performant than loops written in PHP code.

Comment: The difference is negligible for most anyway Manu. Don’t optimize prematurely.

Comment: @ManuM. A foreach loop will always be faster than array_filter because of the overhead of a function call, but as emix states the difference is negligible.

Comment: [Benchmarks on foreach vs array_filter](https://onlinephp.io/c/d4c8b) has some interesting results, where foreach only became **consistently** better after php5.6

Answer (score 6):

The answers here don't actually suggest any reliable way to achieve this... while they do work, they are unreliable in the sense that they're only returning classes that have been loaded, which is not what anyone really wants and is redundant to `instanceof` in the scenarios that these methods are potentially useful for.

`get_declared_classes()`

> Returns an array of the names of the declared classes in the current script.

The keyword here is `current script`, this function will not return classes that have not been loaded yet.

`interface_exists`

Similar to the above, this method will not know if an interface exists, if the interface has not been loaded yet.

It will also autoload the interface (note the second parameter of `interface_exists`)

`class_implements`

Similar to above, this will also autoload your files regardless of your intention to use them.

#### So, how can I reliably retrieve this information, in an efficient way...

Simply put, construct a manifest with all this information and store it in cache.

> Manifests help to cache information which is too expensive to generate on each request. Some manifests generate maps, e.g. class names to filesystem locations. Others store aggregate information like nested configuration graphs.

[Here is a great example](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/4/src/Core/Manifest/ClassManifest.php) of a manifest being constructed in an MVC which serves purely to address the issues in the points above.

There is quite a bit of code to consider in implementing a class manifest accurately, and the complete picture would be a little difficult to post in this answer, however here are a few reference points to get you started:

1. [ClassManifest](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/4/src/Core/Manifest/ClassManifest.php)
2. [ClassManifestVisitor](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/4/src/Core/Manifest/ClassManifestVisitor.php)

The implementation above uses the `nikic/php-parser` package, rather than directly using reflection.