# Discover all class implementing an interface

Tags: php, symfony

Hi I'm using symfony2 framework to make a website. I've defined an interface in PHP like:

```
interface AdminPluginInterface {
    public function getName();
}
```

Now I'd like to know all classes, loadable by Symfony2 UniversalClassLoader, that implements my interface, to use them like:

```
foreach ($classes as $class)
{
    $class->getName();
}
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Symfony can't know all your classes. Autoloader guesses a file's path when you beign to work with undefined class. You'll need to manually iterate over all files in your project and check if a class in it implements an interface. This is not easy. What do you need it for? Maybe you can go with another solution?

Answer (score 3):

Since the classes will load automatically only if they are used, you can't list all the classes in your source code. You can only get the classes that are already being used calling [`get_declared_classes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php).
One solution is to specify a plugins directory and scan it for class files, import them and then check if the classes implements your interface using [`class_implements`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php)
Take a look at [this question answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993759/php-how-to-get-a-list-of-classes-that-implement-certain-interface) for some code examples to scan if your interface is implemented by some declared class

Comment: +1 for pointing out that you can't list all the classes in your source code but only the ones that are currently loaded, which is non trivial to figure out if you don't know how the autoloader works.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `is_a()` function:

```
foreach ($classes as $class)
{
    $classname = $class->getName();
    var_dump(is_a($classname,'AdminPluginInterface'));
}
```

For more info, check out:

- [`is_a()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php)
- [And this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php#72363)

Comment: maybe wrote it bad, I wanna obtain the list of classes implementing that interface in the array `$classes`

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit old, but i think

[`class_implements()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php)

is what you need :)

Comment: `class_implements` does not search through all classes as was asked.