# PHP composer to always load a class

Tags: php, composer-php

How do I configure composer so it always loads a given class? Is such configuration possible in composer.json?

I have a utility class that needs to be loaded all the time, regardless of what part of the PHP code is being executed.

Comment: If autoloading is properly configured, then the class will be available and you don't have to care. What is the added benefit of explicitly loading it for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> #### Files
>
> If you want to require certain files explicitly on every request then you can use the 'files' autoloading mechanism. This is useful if your package includes PHP functions that cannot be autoloaded by PHP.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> {
>    "autoload": {
>        "files": ["src/MyLibrary/functions.php"]
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> -- http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

---

But really, there is no benefit of doing this. Autoloading a class before you use it or autoloading your class when you use it. If you use the class on each request, it's the same. I recommend using the normal autoloading methods, because that means the class isn't loaded when you create something that doesn't need that class.