# Search for classes who implement a certain interface in composer.json's required dependencies

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a PHP library (A) that defines a certain interface.

I have a PHP library (B) that has a class who implementents that interface.

I have PHP cli project that requires both the library and a class that implements the interface.

Currently I have a composer.json file that requires both libaries A and B.

The `composer.json` files in both libraries A and B have definitions for PSR-4 autloading. Is there a way to make PHP look for the class in project B (in the vendor directory) without using require?

I found this answer to a different question that gets close but I assume that it does not work since the class is not (auto)loaded since I never `require` or `use` it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3993796/1053785

An example with my question.

library A specifies

```php
namespace a;

interface Singer{
    public function sing(): void;
}
```

library B specifies:

```php
namespace b;

use a\Singer;

class Clefairy implements Singer{
    public function sing(): void{
        echo "Clefairy...";
    }
}
```

The PHP CLI project's composer file specifies

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        "A": "*",
        "B": "*"
    }
    ...
}
```

And it has a main.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use a\Singer;

function findMeASinger(): Singer{
    // look for classes in vendor/ that implement a Singer and if so, return (the first) instance
}

$singer = findMeASinger(); //b\Clefairy should be found and an instance should be returned.
$singer->sing();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "look for the class without using require"?

Comment: @NicoHaase, I'd like to create a new instance if such a implementation is found. I'm not so familiar with the concepts of class loading in PHP. Java for instance can "scan" all the classes who are available on the classpath.

Comment: How does your code look like? If you use an autoloader (which should be the default nowadays, especially when installing packages using composer), there is no need to require single classes

Comment: @NicoHaase, I've provided an example that might explain it a bit more. Depending on what I define in composer.json -> require (in this case B), I want a Singer but I don't need to know it's name. As far as I know, an autoloader requires a name.

Comment: What do you mean by that? The autoloader takes care of using the class - if you want to instantiate a random class, that's a completely different thing - what's the use case for that? Why do you want to instantiate a random class? Why not use `new Clefairy()` in your function?

Comment: @gadeynebram In PHP you can't have two classes (including interfaces) with the same name. In your case `Singer` is ambiguous - you need to use namespaces to disambiguate these two types (for example `\A\Singer` and `\B\Singer`).

Comment: @rob006, You're right. My example was not clear in that sence. I've now updated it to include namespaces.

Comment: @NicoHaase, the use case here is that I want to create some sort of plugin system.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've got right now is by specifying this in the composer.json file of library B which requires PHP to always load the class file.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "b\\": "src/"
    },
    "files": ["src/Clefairy.php"]
}
```

Then in my PHP CLI project this function finds `b\Clefairy`.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use a\Singer;

function findMeASinger(): Singer{
    $classes = get_declared_classes();
    /**
     * @var $implementsIModule ReflectionClass[]
     */
    $implementsIModule = array();
    foreach($classes as $klass) {
        $reflect = new ReflectionClass($klass);
        if($reflect->implementsInterface('a\Singer')){
            echo "Found Singer $klass\n";
            $implementsIModule[] = $reflect;
        }
    }
    if(sizeof($implementsIModule) > 0){
        return $implementsIModule[0]->newInstance();
    }else{
        throw new \Exception("Could not find a Singer");
    }
}

$singer = findMeASinger(); //b\Clefairy should be found and an instance should be returned.
$singer->sing();
```

Comment: You should use some existing DI library for PHP. `get_declared_classes()` will return only loaded classes, not all available classes. Not mention that this implementation may be pretty slow for big apps.

Comment: @rob006, I agree with that